# Chan-Paton factors for branes in string theory

Tags: string-theory, branes

In open string theory, we can have additional degrees of freedom residing at the string endpoints, in addition to strings propagating. Therefore we can add a new degree of freedom, known as a *Chan-Paton* degree of freedom, which can be in one of $n$ states. A basis of strings is then
$$\left|N;k;ij\right>,$$
where  $i$ and $j$ denote the left and right endpoints.

My question is why can't we have such a generalization for $p$-branes, since branes can also have boundaries, which we can label with new degrees of freedom? Is the Chan-Paton degree of freedom enough to describe possible configuration with branes where the boundary of the branes have extra degrees of freedom?